# Compiled program is replaced by repo version overnight

Tags: apt, vim, compiling

Vim version changes without opening a new terminal, without restarting the computer. Simply, the next day my computer takes the repo version, which has been removed by apt before.

I've compiled vim from the source, because I needed some options, which is not compiled in the repo version. I've done it a few times before, but now on XUbuntu 18.04LTS the system forgets the compiled vim and somehow it pulls back the repo version, what I removed, at least I thought that.
After being unsure whether I do the compilation and the post-compile setup correctly, I was following [this link](https://github.com/ycm-core/YouCompleteMe/wiki/Building-Vim-from-source). I've also used checkinstall and last time I pulled vim8.2 back with `dpkg -i deb_name`, where deb_name is the name of the deb file checkinstall created.

I noticed, that when the compiled vim version is not recognized, the location where it was installed is also not available:

```
~ $ sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/editor editor /usr/local/bin/vim 1
update-alternatives: error: alternative path /usr/local/bin/vim doesn't exist
~ $ ls -l /usr/local/bin/ | grep vi
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      3 Mär 13  2018 ex -> vim
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    216 Feb 15  2019 pyvisa-info
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    218 Feb 15  2019 pyvisa-shell
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      3 Mär 13  2018 rview -> vim
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      3 Mär 13  2018 rvim -> vim
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      3 Mär 13  2018 view -> vim
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      3 Mär 13  2018 vimdiff -> vim
```

This is really strange, since I needed to execute this command to tell my system, where vim was compiled.

The location is on a local drive, the whole `/usr` is one logical volume, so it can not be disconnected.

I have removed vim with `sudo apt remove vim vim-runtime gvim vim-common` ebefore compiling. `dpkg -l | grep vim` has confirmed that I have no vim package installed. Also the shell tells me, that `Command 'vim' not found`. Although some time later - next day - vim is there again from the repo:

```
~ $ dpkg -l vim
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                                 Version                 Architecture            Description
 +++-====================================-=======================-=======================-========================================================
ii  vim                                  2:8.0.1453-1ubuntu1.4   amd64                   Vi IMproved - enhanced vi editor
```

Installing the deb created by checkinstall solves the issue for about a day:

```
~/git_repos/vim $ sudo dpkg -i vim_20201104-1_amd64.deb 
[sudo] password for tibenszky: 
dpkg: warning: downgrading vim from 2:8.0.1453-1ubuntu1.4 to 20201104-1
(Reading database ... 487461 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack vim_20201104-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking vim (20201104-1) over (2:8.0.1453-1ubuntu1.4) ...
Setting up vim (20201104-1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.3-2ubuntu0.1) ...
```

I have no clue what could have cause this issue, or how could I debug and solve this. Any help is appreciated.

**Update**:
It seems like that apt's daily upgrade overwrite my vim version. So the question is changed to 'How do I tell apt that I want to use my compiled version, and not the repo version?'. I've just issues the command `sudo apt-mark hold vim` and hopefully tomorrow vim will not be updated again. I've found the command in this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18654/how-to-prevent-updating-of-a-specific-package).

Comment: `grep -i apt /var/log/syslog` please. Have you got an automated job that updated your system for you?

Comment: @roaima Thanks for the tip! Its' the daily apt upgrade. I was not aware that it is running on my machine.

Answer (score 0):

Please run `grep -i apt /var/log/syslog` and check for an automated job that updates your system for you. If that exists then it can explain why your own binary is being replaced in the `alternatives` subsystem. Presumably you want to stop that happening

```
update-alternatives --config editor 0<&-; echo
There are 4 choices for the alternative editor (providing /usr/bin/editor).

  Selection    Path               Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
* 0            /bin/nano           40        auto mode
  1            /bin/ed            -100       manual mode
  2            /bin/nano           40        manual mode
  3            /usr/bin/vim.nox    40        manual mode
  4            /usr/bin/vim.tiny   15        manual mode

Press <enter> to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number:
```

If you havent' already done so, install your own binary to the configuration set

```
update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/editor editor /usr/local/bin/vim 1
```

However, if you re-run the `--config` command (above) you'll see that you have not yet switched to your own binary. Do this and the alternatives subsystem will see a `manual` selection and should stop changing the setting underneath you. I think this may have been the step you were missing

```
update-alternatives --set editor /usr/local/bin/vim
```